# How to have multiple sections with images in a FluidTYPO3 flux form with TYPO3 10?

Tags: typo3, fluid, flexform

I have been using FluidTYPO3 (flux and vhs) to run TYPO3 web pages for many years now. With TYPO3 10, I face a major problem. I'll quickly write about my use case, how I solved it so far, and then what the problem with 10 LTS is.

**Use case:**
I want to have a content element template for a timeline using FluidTYPO3/flux. Each "point" on the timeline should have a heading, some text, and optionally some images. All in all, pretty basic (or so I thought).

**Solution so far (TYPO3 <= 9):**
Timeline elements are sections. Images are using `flux:field.file`.

Simplified example of the form:

```xml
    <flux:form id="timeline" label="timeline">
        <flux:form.section name="timeline" label="Timeline">
            <flux:form.object name="element" label="Element">
                <flux:field.input name="title" label="Heading" />
                <flux:field.text name="label" label="Text" enableRichText="TRUE" />
                <flux:field.file name="images" label="Pictures" allowed="jpg,png,svg" multiple="TRUE" maxItems="50" size="5" showThumbnails="TRUE"
                />
            </flux:form.object>
        </flux:form.section>
    </flux:form>
```

With this, multiple elements can be created on the timeline and each of them can have its own set of images.

**Problem in TYPO3 10:**
The technology (TCA `group` fields to select files) that `flux:field.file` relies on was deprecated in TYPO3 9 and removed in TYPO3 10, see [this notice](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/9.5/Deprecation-86406-TCATypeGroupInternal_typeFileAndFile_reference.html). That is one of the reasons why `flux:field.file` was also marked deprecated and is going to be removed in TYPO3 10.

The TYPO3 deprecation notice says to use FAL relations instead. Of course, flux can also do this with `flux:field.inline.fal`. However, you can only have one FAL field per FlexForm. This precludes its usage in sections, since all sections would share the same images. This limitation is known for some time - see [this bug report for example](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/71239) - but has never been fixed. It is also why I initially chose not to use FAL fields. Using bare file fields was the recommended workaround at the time.

**Question:**

So - how is everyone doing it? How to add multiple image fields to a flexform in TYPO3 10?
EDIT: More specifically, how to add an image field as part of a Flexform section that can contain multiple child records (resulting in multiple image fields)?

Note: I know that I can get a "file-like" field back by using an `input` field with `inputLink` renderType (like [this](https://github.com/FluidTYPO3/flux/issues/1803#issuecomment-748930459)), but as far as I can tell it does not allow to link multiple images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the only workaround with TYPO3 core onboard methods is to go for a Flux-Container having a single column containing simple default "Text with image" or "text with media" elements and then to just ignore additional options of those elements and to just render the necessary fields.

With Gridelements this is called a "functional container", since the container determines the behaviour and appearance of those elements, while the elements themselves don't have to be custom elements at all.

Additionally this makes access to the content of those elements - i.e. while doing a search query - much easier.

Answer (score 1):

I've found another workaround that might be appropriate for some use cases:

It is still possible to use `flux:field.file` fields if the `useFalRelation` parameter set to true, even on TYPO3 v10 LTS and in repeatable FlexForm sections. This will then put `sys_file` record IDs separated by comma into the field instead of raw filenames. They can be used as `src` argument for, e.g., `f:image` just as well as the filename, so the CE templates itself do not have to be modified. All existing CEs that had `useFalRelation` set to false need to be migrated though so that the filenames are replaced with sys_file UIDs.

This is a bit better than the `inputLink`  workaround since it allows multiple images.

Answer (score 0):

The bug report you mentioned already contains the solutions, since the actual problem described there is that FAL fields in a flexform are using the same name.

So instead of

```
image
```

according to the bug report there should be

```
settings.foreground.image
```

which is of course not working, since the dot is part of the path but not of the name.
But actually replacing the dot with an underscore and using some suffixes within the same flexform tab should do the trick:

```
settings.foreground.settings_foreground_image
settings.foreground.settings_foreground_image2
```

This way you make sure that

1. The field names within your flexform are unique
2. The actual field name within the sys_file_reference entry already contains the full path information
3. You can use that information to fetch images i.e. within a DataProcessor and still know the FlexForm field they actually belong to

Sitll I would recommend to fully move away form FlexForms (and thus Flux too) in favor of "real" fields in the database table.

Comment: While this does work for multiple toplevel image fields, it does not work for Flexform sections/objects. Or does it?

Comment: Regarding the usage of DB tables instead, that is of course a somewhat valid solution to the problem. However, I find that both the development process (having to create database tables, TCA, frontend plugins etc.) and the user experience (having to create the "plugin" content element and the displayed data separately) are not on par with flux. Plus I'm not super stoked to migrate (= recreate content of) 30+ TYPO3 installations :D

Comment: You don't need any "frontend plugin" to display additional data fields of tt_content with Fluid, since the whole data array will be pushed to your fluid template anyway no matter how many fields are in there.

DataProcessing will do the rest and add i.e. images via sys_file references and the like.

The effort for TCA is exactly the same as for FlexForms, since FlexForms are just an XML representation of TCA structures.

Comment: According to the bugreport you mentioned:

"Technically, the issue is that when you save a record that has a FlexForm with a FAL field, the FAL relation is stored using the field name without considering the nesting which means that all your relations have the field name image after they're saved. Of course, when you reload the form, the methods that pre-fill the FAL relation fields are then detecting the same relation in all fields."

So to me this sounds pretty much like: "Using different fieldnames solves the problem"

Comment: Different fieldnames do solve the problem in theory, but AFAIK this option just does not exist for fields in repeatable sections. You can only define one fieldname in the TCA for the field - see the example XML. If the user adds multiple instances of the object into the section, all of them will get the same fieldname on the FAL relation and thus share the same files. The fieldname would need to contain an index for this to actually work.

Comment: OK - fortunuately I am not that much into FlexForms, but I guess that's why I confused the term "sections" with "sheets". That's why I will post another answer now, but will leave this one here, since it contains useful information in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

If you currently use the `flux:field.file` element at typo3 10 with the `useFalRelation=1` you can replace it by the `flux:field` element. It is not deprecated and works in combination with the `flux:form.object` element

Following example:

```
<flux:field.file
    allowed="jpg,png,svg,gif"
    exclude="false"
    label="MyLabel"
    name="myname"
    showThumbnails="1"
    useFalRelation="1"
    maxItems="1"
    minItems="1"
/>
```

Can be replaced with:

```
<flux:field type="input" name="myname" label="MyLabel"
    config="{
        type: 'group',
        size: 1,
        internal_type: 'db',
        use_fal_relation: 1,
        allowed: 'sys_file',
        maxitems: 1,
        minitems: 0,
        show_thumbs: 1,
        appearance: {
            elementBrowserAllowed: 'jpg,png,svg,gif',
            elementBrowserType: 'file'
        }
    }
"/>
```